# ffmpeg configure ERROR: libx264 not found

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, configure, libx264

I want to configure ffmpeg on Ubuntu 64 bit, but I get an error: "**ERROR: libx264 not found**".
ffmpeg doesn’t see libx264! Before that, I successfully configure it in QNX and Windows.
I prevented a known bug with `--disable-opencl` , but it did not help.
In my project the **libx264** should be **static**.

libx264 configure:

```
../configure --prefix=x264 --disable-cli --enable-static --disable-opencl

platform:      X86_64
byte order:    little-endian
system:        LINUX
cli:           no
libx264:       internal
shared:        no
static:        yes
asm:           yes
interlaced:    yes
avs:           no
lavf:          no
ffms:          no
mp4:           no
gpl:           yes
thread:        posix
opencl:        no
filters:       crop select_every
lto:           no
debug:         no
gprof:         no
strip:         no
PIC:           no
bit depth:     all
chroma format: all
```

it's OK! Confused only **platform: X86_64**

FFmpeg configure:

```
../configure --target-os=linux --prefix=ffmpeg --disable-programs \
--disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-doc \ 
--disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages \ 
--disable-txtpages --disable-avdevice --disable-postproc \
--disable-network --disable-encoders --enable-encoder=libx264 \
--disable-decoders --enable-decoder=h264 --disable-hwaccels \
--disable-muxers --enable-muxer=matroska --disable-demuxers \
--disable-parsers --enable-parser=h264 --enable-gpl \
--enable-libx264 \
--extra-ldflags=-L../x264/lib \
--extra-cflags=-I../x264/include

    ERROR: libx264 not found
```

Paths exactly correct!

if delete `--enable-libx264`:

```
install prefix            ffmpeg
source path               /home/osuser/develop/libs/source/ffmpeg-3.4.2
C compiler                gcc
C library                 glibc
ARCH                      x86 (generic)
big-endian                no
runtime cpu detection     yes
standalone assembly       yes
x86 assembler             nasm
...
```

This is what worries me... Why **x86**?

ARCH **x86** (generic)

**x86** assembler nasm

Maybe this is the problem? How to configure ffmpeg in x86_64?
`--arch=x86_64` not help!

**UPDATE:**
The problem is fixed, when configure libx264, need to add `--enable-pic`

Comment: What does ffbuild/config.log say? And why are you compiling 3.4.2? It from 2017.

Comment: @Gyan, thanks!!! Analyzed the log ... I saw errors: `relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol x264_cabac_entropy can not be used when making a PIE  object; recompile with -fPIC` , understood the reason. The old version is used, because the first version was build for Windows back in 2017, since then it has not changed

Comment: Whow! It worked adding --enable-pic. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `ERROR: libx264 not found`

You're using a custom `--prefix` for x264 so you need to add `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` for your ffmpeg configure such as:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/path/to/your/x264/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) for another example.

> This is what worries me... Why x86?

Looks like it is just an alias that includes `i[3-6]86*|i86pc|BePC|x86pc|x86_64|x86_32|amd64`. Refer to the contents of `configure`.

It also shows `x86` for me on `x86_64` (without using `--arch` or `--target`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I read the detailed manual. Looked at errors in a log, understood that it is necessary to collect libx264 with parameter `--enable-pic`